# Why does Sinon FakeServer does not trigger with sinon >= 7.4.1?

Tags: javascript, testing, npm, sinon, yarnpkg

At foodsharing.de we have some Sinon tests. Currently there is version <7.4.1 used but I wanted to upgrade it. According to the changelog there should be no issue, still: it won't work.

Here is the test: https://gitlab.com/foodsharing-dev/foodsharing/blob/41ae6e89dfa71903ee4d57b12fe34abd0a3f5913/client/src/script.test.js#L52

What fails is the mock browser on line 53:

```
mockBrowser
    .expects('goTo')
    .once()
    .withArgs(`/?page=msg&cid=${conversationId}`)
```

The error output:

```
1) script
   "after each" hook for "redirects to user chat page":
 ExpectationError: Expected goTo(/?page=msg&cid=10[, ...]) once (never called)
```

It seems that the ajax request is never executed, or at least there is no response? I am really not sure why does this happen.

[`script.chat(fsId)`](https://gitlab.com/foodsharing-dev/foodsharing/blob/41ae6e89dfa71903ee4d57b12fe34abd0a3f5913/client/src/script.js#L249) calls [`conv.userChat(fsid)`](https://gitlab.com/foodsharing-dev/foodsharing/blob/41ae6e89dfa71903ee4d57b12fe34abd0a3f5913/client/src/conv.js#L63) which then calls `ajax.req` in the [`script.js`](https://gitlab.com/foodsharing-dev/foodsharing/blob/41ae6e89dfa71903ee4d57b12fe34abd0a3f5913/client/src/script.js#L376).

It even calls the `complete` callback function with version >=7.4.1 but no fail and no success callback function is called...

**Edit:** I added a `.then(...)` to the `ajax.req` call in `conv.js`. It gets triggered with sinon < 7.4.1 but not with newer versions... What is going on?!

Any ideas what is wrong? Did Sinon change anything back then?

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.